# Java SWT How to prevent shell child from overlapping it's parent?

Tags: java, shell, swt, parent-child

I have a shell (SWT) and it's child. The child overlaps it's parent, so I can't fill some data there. How do I make it possible to switch between parent and child without them overlapping each other? Which style constant should I use when I create the child?
I tried to find the appropriate one but I failed.
Are there other ways to deal with the problem?

Comment: Can you explain the use-case? It's hard to tell why you want to do this?

Comment: Ok, for instance, i have two windows, in one of which i can change some data and so change the picture in the other window. And the window with the picture is a child of the data window. The problem is the picture window overlapping the data window so it's hard to change information in it. I believe that can clarify the problem.

Comment: OK, fair enough. But why two separate windows?

Comment: Well, the picture is rather large and in general i think that if the problem has an easy solution it would be more convinient to use two separate windows :) That's all.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just thinking that if you don't want the shells to overlap it's basically the same as having both components in the same shell.